# C# UWP textfile to list of strings

Tags: list, uwp, text-files, windowsiot

I'm creating a `UWP` application (latest windows IoT) for my raspberry.

I'm trying to get a list of strings from a `.txtfile` located in the project folder under a map called Words.

This is my code so far.

```
public async void GenereerGokWoord(int character)
{
    StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(
                               new Uri("ms-appx:///Words//5-letterwoorden.txt")
                             );
    }
```

By setting a breakpoint at the end of the `}` I can confirm that this code can find the `.txt` file.

But now I don't know how to get a list of strings from this point on.

The `.txt` file looks like things

> word 1
>
> word 2
>
> word 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want contents of file as a List with each line as an Item, Use `FileIO.ReadLinesAsync()`

```
IList<string> data = await FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(file);
List<string> finallist = data.ToList();
```

Your finallist should contain all words as List.

Comment: I think @Wouter Hollanders write two `//` in uri , "ms-appx:///Words//5-letterwoorden.txt"